# Rails too many redirects although it reaches desired page that doesn't redirect anywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I am trying to prevent a logged user from registering and hence I have the following code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include SessionHelper
  before_action :new , :notLoggedIn


    def notLoggedIn()
        if logged_in?
            redirect_to current_user
        end
    end
```

There is more code into the controller however it is irrelevant. (I think?). Here is the logged_in? function from the `SessionHelper`

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

Whenever I do log in (at the moment this is done automatically by registering. There is no page to actually login although I am not sure if this is relevant) the expected page `users/7` is in the URL however the browser tells me that there was an infinite loop which in turn doesn't display the page.

The `show` method doesn't actually do anything apart from loading the user into a instance variable

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Am I braking some rails principle that I don't know? Why does the browser display the relevant url but it doesn't render it and instead it tells me `This webpage has a redirect loop`

Comment: I bet 'new' isn't a before_action

Comment: @Swards Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New is usually one of the RESTful actions, not a before action.  Did you mean this?

```
before_action :notLoggedIn, :only => :new
```